# Use SQL Server to publish to rabbitmq via amqp

Tags: sql, sql-server, rabbitmq

I am looking for specific help setting up message types/contracts/queues and EA to post notifications of SQL table update/inserts to an existing RabbitMQ system.  The destination quese already exist. SQL-to-SQL documentation exists, but not going SQL-to-RabbitMQ.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you want to have a sql table insert/update to send a rabbitmq message?

If you wanted to do this, there are several ways I could imagine this being setup, though I think this maybe bad practice.

You could create a sql clr to allow sql server to send a rabbit msg and then incorporate that into the insert/update, either by adding it to the stored procs if ones are used, or maybe setting up a job that uses change tracking.